# Swift / Array of Images in UIImage only last Image is displayed multiple times

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
    var posts = [EventPosts]() {
    didSet {
        eventsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

    //MARK:PLACEHOLDER IMAGES
    var eventImagesPlaceholder: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "wildstyle.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "geilesleben.jpg")!]  

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let event = posts[indexPath.row]
    let cell = eventsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("eventsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsCollectionViewCell

    for element in eventImagesPlaceholder {
        cell.eventsImageView.image = element
    }

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        offlineModusLabel.hidden = true
        let imgURL = NSURL(string: event.imageUrl)!
        cell.eventsImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imgURL)            
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    } else {           
        offlineModusLabel.hidden = false
    }


    return cell
}
```

If I turn the internet on, four images from the desired source will be parsed and correctly displayed. If I turn the internet off, just the last placeholder image will be displayed 4 times. If I set wildstyle.jpg last, it is displayed four times. If I set geilesleben.jpg last, only that one is.

How can I display BOTH placeholder images. optimally only one time each.

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: now I have four empty frames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this, the two placeholder images are displayed in all cells alternately.

If you add more placeholder images to the array, the number of items will be considered automatically.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let event = posts[indexPath.row]
  let cell = eventsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("eventsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsCollectionViewCell

  if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    offlineModusLabel.hidden = true
    let imgURL = NSURL(string: event.imageUrl)!
    cell.eventsImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imgURL)
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
  } else {
    offlineModusLabel.hidden = false
    cell.eventsImageView.image = eventImagesPlaceholder[indexPath.row % eventImagesPlaceholder.count]
  }

  return cell
}
```

In your code always the last image is displayed because of the repeat loop which assigns all images to the same image view and keeps the last image.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.eventsImageView.image = nil
}
```

in your cell's class

Comment: still four times the same picture

Comment: why is this

`for element in eventImagesPlaceholder {
        cell.eventsImageView.image = element
    }`

Comment: sorry that i didnt gave you an upvote back then. just caught up. thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in eventImagesPlaceholder {
        cell.eventsImageView.image = element
    }
```

change this loop statment to like this

```
let element = eventImagesPlaceholder.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! UIImage
   cell.eventsImageView.image = element
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for element in eventImagesPlaceholder {
    cell.eventsImageView.image = element
}
```

This iterates for every cell you have. Basically every cell gets every image and keeps the last. pretty straight forward

What you want to do is sth like this:

```
cell.eventsImageView.image = eventImagesPlaceholder[someKindOfIndex]
```

Instead of that for loop.
Like when you know you have 4 cells and 4 images in your placeholder variable, just take indexPath.row as "someKindOfIndex"